# How to fix "scintillation" artifacts in shader-created shapes?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

I am currently writing a program in OpenGL where I render a part of the scene using just the fragment shader, not with textures (which makes it not solvable with mipmaps). The part in question is a grid, which is part of the scene and thus gets moved around and scaled quite frequently. The issue, however, is that it seems that whenever the camera is in a multiple of 45° angle, some scintillation artifacts appear absurdly, especially when translating the view.

Here is an example:

[Uneven grid lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOTRS.jpg)

The quality is not great, but you can still see that the grid lines are completely uneven, when they should be getting rendered with the same width all of them.

This is the part of the code that generates the grid lines:

```
if (uDrawGrid) {
    // Texture coordinates.
    float x = fTexCoordinate.x;
    float y = fTexCoordinate.y;
    // Rounding the coordinates to 3 decimals, 
    // so we have the targetX and targetY of the grid, for this fragment.
    float targetX = round(x * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
    float targetY = round(y * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
    // Factor is basically the width of the grid lines, 
    // inversely proportional to the size of the underlying texture.
    vec2 factor = vec2(0.05 / uTexSize.x, 0.05 / uTexSize.y);
    // dx and dy are the distances from the current position to the target, plus a small offset.
    float dx = abs(x - targetX + factor.x / 20.0);
    float dy = abs(y - targetY + factor.y / 20.0);
    // Checking if the distances are smaller than the grid line widths.
    if (dx <= factor.x || dy <= factor.y) {
        // Blending with grid color being (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        color.a = 1.0;
        color.r = 0.25 + topColor.r * 0.5;
        color.g = 0.25 + topColor.g * 0.5;
        color.b = 0.25 + topColor.b * 0.5;
        return;
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. `uDrawGrid` is a boolean just to check if the grid should be drawn.
2. `uTexSize` is a vec2 variable containing the size of the underlying texture that the grid is drawn over.
3. The blending part is just drawing the grid lines over whatever is beneath.
4. `precision highp float;` and `precision highp int;` are already set at the top of the shader.
5. This artifact *does not happen* as soon as the camera angle is something less "even", say, 13.59°.

Question:
How can I avoid that effect from happening? Is there some kind of mathematical formula I should use (replacing my original) so that the lines are always drawn with the same amount of pixels of width?

Edit:
In the image, the uneven grid lines I mean are the smaller ones. The big cross on the corner is part of the background texture, and the circle is a tap on Android.

Comment: This is akin to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moiré_pattern effect. Not much can be done, if you need to draw 100 evenly spaced black and white lines into 95 pixels width, especially when AA/mipmaps is enabled.

Comment: Hmmm yes that seems to be the issue. I'll post an answer if I find a work-around. Thanks! :)

Comment: One of the workarounds could be rendering each line rounded to the pixel grid, thus having perfectly sharp lines, but spaced unevenly (+/-1px). Another one - dynamic grid step, change to 1:10, 1:20, 1:50, 1:100, etc.. so that you have approx 1 gridline per 10px or so, then unevenness from previous approach will be unnoticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish someone would have taught me graphics like this when I was younger:

You have defined the colour of your grid as a function of the uv coordinates.
That's cool.  But to render this function, each pixel should technically be coloured as the **average value** of your function across the area of the pixel. Mathematically, that's the integral of your function over the area of the pixel divided by the area of the pixel.

You have four choices:

1. Ignore the problem and point-sample your parametric function exactly once per fragment.  Enjoy your scintillating artifacts.
2. Use full-screen anti-aliasing (FSAA) or multi-sample anti-aliasing (MSAA) to have the rasterizer compute your fragment multiple times and average the result.  Lose performance proportional to the MSAA factor.
3. Have your shader sample your parametric function at multiple places for each fragment and manually compute the average by samping N times.  Lose performance proportional to N.
4. Directly compute the definite integral of your parametric function over the area of the pixel.  Best choice, if you can do the math.

Generalized to one dimension, your parametric function of grid lines is an *asymmetric square wave*, and its indefinite integral can easily be characterized in two sections.  It is rising when the square wave is high and steady when the square wave is low.  Graphically it looks something like this:

[image: Step function and its integral]

This function must be integrated over the area of the pixel that the current fragment is rendering.  In the diagram that's the range from a to b.  It's important to note that when the grid lines become small relative to the pixel that the pixel may entirely or partially enclose any portion of any number of grid lines.

To compute the intensity of the pixel, you evaluate the integral exactly twice, once at the min and max of the range covered by the pixel, then subtract those values and divide by the area of the pixel to get the intensity that best represents the average intensity over the entire pixel.

Visualizing the integral of the grid function like this in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) makes it fairly intuitive to write the code to compute the integral in the shader.

In my example I expressed the width of the grid line as a portion of the spacing between the lines.  You did yours a little differently, but I think my form is easier to integrate.

Here is an implementation for you.  You can copy and paste this code into [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) to try it online.

```
// Integral of the line's cross-section intensity function
vec2 g(vec2 uv, float portion) {
    vec2 c = vec2(1.0, 1.0) * portion;
    vec2 t = floor(mod(-uv - c / 2.0, 1.0) + c);

    vec2 whole = floor(uv + c / 2.0);
    vec2 frac = (uv + c / 2.0) - whole;

    vec2 rising = (frac + whole * c);
    vec2 steady = (c / 2.0 + whole * c) + c / 2.0;
    return mix(steady, rising, t);
}

float linearToSRGB(float linear) {
    if (linear <= 0.0031308) {
       return 12.92 * linear;
    } else {
       return 1.055 * pow(linear, 1.0/2.2) - 0.055;
    }
    return linear;
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // You can choose gnarly numbers here for gridSize and lineWidth
    float gridSize = 5.13;
    float lineWidth = 0.55;
    
    float fraction = lineWidth / gridSize;
    vec2 uv = fragCoord / gridSize;
    vec2 pixelSize = vec2(1.0, 1.0) / gridSize;
    vec2 average = (g(uv + pixelSize, fraction) - g(uv, fraction)) / pixelSize;
    float linear = max(average.x, average.y);
    vec3 srgb = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * linearToSRGB(linear);
    fragColor = vec4(srgb.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

Example output:

[image: Example output of anti-aliased grid]

Comment: Incredible answer! :) As a physics student, I get the math, but the graphics programming not too much haha. I managed to adapt your example code, and it works great! I just have a few questions to understand it better: First, what exactly is being represented by "linear", and what is its range? Secondly, why does the `sRGB` converter function return a float? I'm a newbie to color spaces but up until now I always saw RGB colors as integers. Third, if `average` returns the average value of the function over the pixel area, wouldn't it be better for `linear` to be `(average.x + average.y) * 0.5`?

Comment: Short story: it's _gamma correction_.  Many people think that the code that we store in a red, green or blue channel of a pixel is directly proportional to the luminance (brightness) of the light it represents - bad news: it's not.  Rather, each code point is some _percentage_ more than the previous one.  That's an _exponential_ function (a rising curve) not _linear_ (not a straight line).  See [What is gamma?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction)  Improper treatment of gamma is the most widespread _error_ in all of computer graphics.

Comment: And no, `linear` should not be the average of `average.x` and `average.y`.  The square waves that model the cross-sectional brightness don't add up where they intersect.  The confluence points (crossings) of the grid lines aren't intended to be twice as bright as the rest of the lines.  But rather the _same_ brightness as the rest of the lines.  `max` is the right thing.

Comment: `linear` is intended to represent how bright the pixel should be at that point.  It's a value that ranges linearly from 0.0 = black to 1.0 = white.  Or you can think of 0.0 = the background color and 1.0 = the foreground (line) colour.

Comment: I see! So like, the perceived brightness difference between, say, `RGB(20, 20, 20)` and `RGB(40, 40, 40)` is not the same as the difference between `RGB(160, 160, 160)` and `RGB(180, 180, 180)`? Thank you for the detailed explanation, I think I get what you did much better now.